# Libraries for processing multiple Streams

Tags: spring-boot, java-stream, etl

I need advice on building an application that will:

- connect to a stream of Content-Type: text/event-stream
- there can be 1+ streams (all streams have the same data model)
- aggregate incoming messages from all streams in-memory

If possible I would like to use Spring Boot as foundation and add libraries to it so I can achieve the above task.

From what I have read, I need ETL tools, but I do not know which ones and how to combine them. (I might need only one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found exactly what I need in WebFlux [as explained here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events)